# GitLab v4 API update file with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gitlab, gitlab-api

I am trying to update a certain file in my GitLab repo using the v4 API and Google Apps Script.

As we can see [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#update-existing-file-in-repository), the payload have to be inserted in the url.
This is where problem begins, Google Apps Script throws an error like this:
`Limit Exceeded: URLFetch URL Length.`
Which only occurs when the file contents **is too large** (which makes sense).

Could you please have a look and give an insight on this?

Thank you!

Comment: The link "here" has a wrong URL. Who is throwing the error the GitLab API or Apps Script?

Comment: Apps script, because the URL is too long. Fixed the url.

Comment: Can you provide your latest script including the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created an issue on GitLab and now they replied.
You can see the thread here https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/49869